# Advice for disclaimer pop up Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions

Just looking for some advice.

I have a request to provide a 'Disclaimer pop up' which appears on screen the first time an external user visits one of our sites.  Once the user has clicked ok, the disclaimer will close, and never be shown again.

We have implemented this so far using a web part.  Everything works fine, we have a list that records those users that have clicked ok and read it so they dont get the pop up again.  However, I don't like the fact that it is a WebPart and therefore needs to be added to every site that we create.

Is there a way of using a SPFX Extension to do this instead?  The theory is that the extension will run on every visit to any page in our Sharepoint and therefore doesn't need to be added on each site as a Web Part.

I've used an application customizer extension before to add CSS to a page before, and wondered if an Extension can be used in this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilise an SPFx application customiser instead and then deploy that to many sites. Unlike web parts, application customisers can utilise page placeholders on SharePoint pages.

[Overview of SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)

Comment: Cool, that's what I was thinking of using. Just wanted to confirm I was heading in the right direction  Thanks

Comment: You mentioning placeholders was the key for me it seems.  Thank you again!